# Plot Cayley graphs for generic element groups

Tags: gap, sagemath, cayley-graphs

I'm a beginner in Abstract Algebra, currently trying to solve all exercises in "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by Pinter. I was wondering if there is a way to draw Cayley graphs for generic element groups like for example for the group

$G=\{e,a,b,b^2,b^3,ab,ab^2,ab^3\}$ with the generators satisfying $a^2=e,b^4=e,ba=ab^2$. I plotted the diagram myself but I would like to double check with the help of a program, plus further experiment before getting to more advanced topics like symmetries, etc. So far I've seen that GAP and Sage plot Cayley graphs but for predefined groups. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may find https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/icXf7xm155M helpful.

Comment: Good question!  @kcrisman The link shows how to construct Cayley graphs in SAGE if we know the permutation group explicitly.  But what if the generator set is $\{a,b\}$ and the group is defined only in terms of relations on $a$ and $b$? Is there a way to construct the Cayley graphs using a computer?

Comment: Of course there "is" a way but you may have to do it by actually constructing edges and vertices 'by hand'.

Answer (score 1):

[This repository](https://github.com/caten2/AlgebraicStructure) contains some tools I wrote to draw a generalized version of Cayley graphs, which I call "operation digraphs", for arbitrary binary operations.